# Node - Wait for loop to finish?

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop, asynchronous, callback

When the function below finishes and provides a finalized list of items in the array 'albums', I want it to call another function/do something else with the list.

Currently it posts [] before the function finishes and I know that's because of asynchronous execution, but I thought Node read linearly since it's single threaded?

```
function getAlbumsTotal(list, params){
    for(var i = 0; i<list.length; i++){
        api.getArtistAlbums(list[i], params).then(function(data) {
            for(var alb = 0; alb<data.body.items.length; alb++){
                albums.push(data.body.items[alb].id);
            }
        }, function(err) {
            console.error(err);
        });
    }
    console.log(albums);
    //do something with the finalized list of albums here
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The callback function you provide to `then` is indeed executed asynchronously, which means it is only executed after the rest of the code in the current call stack has finished executing, including your final `console.log`.

Here is how you could do it:

```
function getAlbumsTotal(list, params){
    var promises = list.map(function (item) { // return array of promises
        // return the promise:
        return api.getArtistAlbums(item, params)
            .then(function(data) {
                for(var alb = 0; alb<data.body.items.length; alb++){
                    albums.push(data.body.items[alb].id);
                }
            }, function(err) {
                console.error(err);
            });
    });
    Promise.all(promises).then(function () {
        console.log(albums);
        //do something with the finalized list of albums here
    });
}
```

NB: Apparently `albums` is defined as a global variable. This is not so good a design. It would be better that each promise would provide its own subset of albums, and the `Promise.all` call would be used to concatenate those results into a local variable. Here is how that would look like:

```
function getAlbumsTotal(list, params){
    var promises = list.map(function (item) { // return array of promises
        // return the promise:
        return api.getArtistAlbums(item, params)
            .then(function(data) {
                // return the array of album IDs:
                return Array.from(data.body.items, function (alb) {
                    return alb.id;
                });
            }, function(err) {
                console.error(err);
            });
    });
    Promise.all(promises).then(function (albums) { // albums is 2D array
        albums = [].concat.apply([], albums); // flatten the array
        console.log(albums);
        //do something with the finalized list of albums here
    });
}
```

Comment: Is this the most elegant way to do it? What if i were to not use .then and used something like this instead

`function getAlbumsTotal(list, params){
    for(var i = 0; i<list.length; i++){
        api.getArtistAlbums(list[i], params, function(err, data){
            if(!err){
                for(var alb = 0; alb<data.body.items.length; alb++){
                    albums.push(data.body.items[alb].id);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}`

would it be the same solution? Edit: I guess it doesnt add the spaces, but instead of .then, its a function of the function.

Comment: The asynchronicity is still there: you still have a callback function that executes after anything else that is currently running. So in fact, you are better of with promises, because of things like `Promise.all` which brings it all together. Without that, you'll have to start counting when you are at the last call of the callback.

Comment: I extended my answer with a version which works with a local variable `albums` instead of a global one, which (depending on what else you do with it), would be better design.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use data returned from a loop in node.js you have to add a little extra code to check if you're on the last iteration of the loop. Basically you're writing your own "loop complete" check and running only when that condition is true.

I went ahead and wrote a complete, runnable example so you can break it down to see how it works. The important part is to add a counter, increment it after each loop, then check for when the counter is the same length of the list that you're iterating over.

```
function getArtistAlbums(artist, params){
  var artistAlbums = {
    'Aphex Twin':['Syro', 'Drukqs'],
    'Metallica':['Kill \'Em All', 'Reload']
  };
  return new Promise(function (fulfill, reject){
    fulfill(artistAlbums[artist]);
  });

}
function getAlbumsTotal(list, params){
  var listCount = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i<list.length; i++){
    getArtistAlbums(list[i], params)
      .then(function(data) {
        listCount++;
        for(var alb = 0; alb<data.length; alb++){
        //for(var alb = 0; alb<data.items.length; alb++){
          //albums.push(data.body.items[alb].id);
          albums.push(data[alb]);
        }
        // print out album list at the end of our loop
        if(listCount == list.length){
          console.log(albums);
        }

      }, function(err) {
        console.error(err);
      });
  }
  // prints out too early because of async nature of node.js
  //console.log(albums);
}

var listOfArtists = ['Aphex Twin', 'Metallica'];
var albums = [];

getAlbumsTotal(listOfArtists, 'dummy params');
```